# 'Lightning Component Tabs' new tab section not available

Tags: salesforce1-app

In developer edition new Lightning features are available, I am able to create new Lightning Application, Component etc. but 'Lightning Component Tabs' section isn't available.

As mentioned in https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lightning_components/lightning_components_creating trailhead when I goto Setup>Create>Tabs there I cannot see section for creating new lightning components.

Any idea how to make it available?[image: Missing Lightning Component Section]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you going to lightning view at least one time? Also problem might be that you don't have any lightning components. Try to create few components at first. [image]

Comment: Hi..Yes lightning view is enabled in my dev org also I have created few components with '<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">' markup and still unable to get lightning component tabs section.

Comment: Do you add a domain for your org?

Comment: hey thanks able to resolve it...domain name was created for my dev org but it wasn't deployed to users...I did that step and now able to create new lightning component tabs.

Comment: @Yaroslav_Maksymenko Thanks so much for this. I just migrated code to a new org to test out Salesforce DX and couldn't for the life of me figure out why my lightning component tabs weren't showing. You'd think they'd give some sort of indication to the problem here.